# Indexing $or queries on the same field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Why does the query: `{ $or: [ {tags: {$in: ['foo']}}, {tags: {$nin: ['bar']}} ] }` NOT use an index on `tags`?

Comment: Its because of $nin operator. This query will be very complex, if it uses index also, it will have to scan all index entries and bring most of the documents from disk, and will be very slow. You can test by proving hint as hint({tags : 1}). Also to test, you can change $nin to $in and check it will gracefully use the index.

Comment: do you realize that your query is exactly equivalent to the query { tags : {$nin : ['bar']}} ? Which is exactly equivalent to { tags : {$ne: 'bar' }}) which *does* use the index?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky is rigth. Maybe you oversimplified your example ? Add some details to it. If not, the simple query suggested will work.